# Short XLR connections via XLR 'cables' or separate wires?

Tags: cables, wire, xlr

I'm intending to create a so called patch box (for audio signals), with 16 channels. Each channel has 2 female XLR and 2 male XLR connectors which are tied together (all 3 wires).

The distance between 3 of the connections is about 2-4 inches, the distance to the fourth is about 8 inches.

Is it recommendable to use the (shielded) XLR cable for all these short distances, or can I (especially for the 3 short distances) use 3 separate 24AWG wires?

In schematic form:

```
XLR Female 1, pin 1      XLR Female 1, pin 2       XLR Female 1, pin 3
       ^                          ^                         ^
       |                          |                         |
    2 inches                   2 inches                2 inches
       |                          |                         |
       V                          V                         V
XLR Female 2, pin 1      XLR Female 2, pin 2       XLR Female 2, pin 3
       ^                          ^                         ^
       |                          |                         |
    2 inches                   2 inches                2 inches
       |                          |                         |
       V                          V                         V
XLR Male 1, pin 1        XLR Male 1, pin 2         XLR Male 1, pin 3
       ^                          ^                         ^
       |                          |                         |
    8 inches                   8 inches                8 inches
       |                          |                         |
       V                          V                         V
XLR Male 2, pin 1        XLR Male 2, pin 2         XLR Male 2, pin 3
```

We probably will never going to use phantom power (48V), but don't want to rule it fully out. Both microphone level (few uV?) and line levels (max around 1 V?) are used.

We use both microphone and line level instruments.

Or more as a generic question? For what maximum distance it is not needed to use shielded wiring (regarding XLR)?

Comment: I’d recommend using a well shielded, balanced cable. That’s typically two pairs twisted together and a third (often without its own plastic sheath) as the shield. For these short distances it’s unlikely anything fancy will be required, but if you use individual strands with lots of cables bundled nearby there is a slightly higher chance of crosstalk or noise. Fine for the guitar feeding into a beefy DI box, not so good for an unpowered microphone.

Comment: @David Thanks for that info, there will be cables on the other side, and possibly I want also to redirect all signals to an off-board (for later usage with an Arduino or so). However, I don't understand what you mean with 'two pairs'? Because an XLR(3) for audio (both mic and guitar) has only three wires (one is ground), what do you mean with two pairs?

Comment: Poorly worded on my behalf, one pair or two individual wires.